# draft.js contentState.createEntity is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, wysiwyg, draftjs

I copied the example of the draft.js editor and run it. 
This is an example from the official repository.
https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/blob/master/examples/draft-0-10-0/link/link.html
But when you click on the button

```
<button onMouseDown={this.confirmLink}> Confirm</button>
```

[image]

The function `_confirmLink` fails:

```
Uncaught TypeError: contentState.createEntity is not a function


  _confirmLink(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      const {editorState, urlValue} = this.state;
      const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
      console.log('contentState->', contentState) 
      const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity('LINK', 'MUTABLE', {url: urlValue});
```

Draft.js can not create an entity. console.log('contentState->', contentState) outputs to the console:

[image]

What could be the problem in this case?

Comment: what the draft version you use

Comment: If you are using 0.9.x version, you should probably call Entity.create(). Entities are moved to contentState in 0.10 version of draft.js. see: 
http://facebook.github.io/draft-js/docs/api-reference-entity.html and
https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/839

Comment: Yes, I used the 0.9 version of the editor. And examples for 0.10 version and it turned out that there is no backwards compatibility.